# $f: A\rightarrow A$ total function, is $f \circ f$ a bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: A\rightarrow A$ be a [total function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalFunction.html).
>   Is $f \circ f$ a bijection?

Comment: @user1518183 what does "All possible input values" mean here? Is a total function then just one whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$? $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @AlkaKadri: Whose domain is arbitrary.

Comment: @AlkaKadri The convention the OP uses is: *partial function* $A\to B$ = a subset $f\subseteq A\times B$ such that, for all $(a,b_1),(a,b_2)\in f$, $b_1=b_2$; *total function* $A\to B$ = a partial function $f:A\to B$ such that for all $a\in A$ there is some $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you clarified in the comment, I am assuming that a *total function* is a function that is defined for all $a \in A$.

With this assumption, it is easy to devise many examples in which $f \circ f$ is not a bijection. Take for example $$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ to be a constant function.

Answer (score 4):

$f\circ f$ is a bijection if and only if $f$ is a bijection in the first place. Exercise for you is to prove it.